# trying to make a currency system in discord.js (Balance not shop)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, currency

OK so sorry for posting "Again" but I wanna make a currency/balance system but idk how to make the system. I'm tryna explain it lol, ok so, I want to have the values save when you use b!bake command i dont really want too add a shop just something that will keep and display balance. This is my code so far

```
'if (message.content === prefix + "bake") {
message.channel.send("you baked" + " " + random + " " + "Cookies! :3 :cookie:")
var currency = ("Cookies") }'
```

If anyone can help me with this please do.

Comment: Hey April. Do you have a way to save users 'currency'? Like a database?

Comment: Not sure Use glitch to keep my bot online

Comment: @Nathan Thats kinda what i wanted too know. I want to know how to make a database to save the users currency amount

Comment: Been trying to think of what's best, honestly.

Looking at Glitch they seem to offer the ability to store files locally in a `.data` folder. Maybe this would be the best shout as it's guranteed to keep costs down (free!).

Amazon also offer a Free tier but requires a bit more setup. Same with MongoDB Atlas which again offers a free tier.

Comment: OK, im kinda a beginner to coding do I dont really understand that lol, But ik what you mean. So what would i put in the .data file

Comment: Add a reference to the file inside your JS; `const json = require('./data/data.json');`. Then you can use Node's `filesystem` module to write to it. `const fs = require('fs')` `fs.writeFile('./data/data.json', JSON.stringify(json), () => console.log('saved!'))`

Comment: ok tysm, btw how would i go about using s command to display the users currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I do not recommend storing data inside a json file no matter the size of your project**

If youre using glitch, then I suggest `quick.db`. Its a wrapper for better-sqlite3 which is very very fast. It is stored inside a file inside your project and is easily accessible.

Once you have quick.db:

1. You can use db.fetch / db.set / db.delete / db.add / db.subtract to help you use the database
2. Example: db.set('balance' + message.author.id, 5)
3. Example to get balance: let balance = db.fetch('balance' + message.author.id) || 0

Answer (score 0):

The Discord.js Guide has a guide for this, have a look [here](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#file-overview). It uses Sequelize and sqlite3. And as `kingschool9` said, you shouldn't use a JSON file in projects for storing data.